# Get values from checkbox to calender

Tags: javascript

I'm new to this. And have a code. HTML form that has 4 Checkboxes
The result goes into a G-spreadsheet. From the Sheet I want the checked boxes values to polulate a Calendar event. Now it works but I get all the Checkboxes values in the calendar. Not only the ones that are checked.

```
function appendData(data){
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Records");
  Logger.log(data)
  // Lägg till rad i spreadsheet
  ws.appendRow([data.name, data.email, data.cuser, data.lastday, data.telenor, data.comment, data.company, data.costacc, data.laptop, data.ipad, data.printer, data.router]);
```

```
// Create data for event
  var title = data.name + " börjar sin anställning på Roche"
  var date = new Date(data.lastday)
  var description = "<b>Mobil + Abonnemang:</b>\n" + data.telenor + "\n\n" +
    "<b>Bolag:</b>\n" + data.company + "\n\n" +
    "<b>Övrig utrustning:</b>\n" + data.laptop + ", " + data.ipad + ", " + data.printer + ", " + data.router
    "<b>Kopiera rättigheter från:</b>\n" + data.cuser + "\n\n" +
    "<b>Övriga kommentarer:</b>\n" +
      data.comment
```

Comment: Could you please clarify how the code snippets connect to your description? and how do they connect between them?

Comment: Checkboxes? Do you mean `<input type='checkbox'>` ? If not, post a google-sheet tag so I can avoid this question in the future. If so, post the HTML and a google-sheet tag so I can avoid this question in the future.

Comment: Code looks like this in HTML
```<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<i class="material-icons prefix">computer</i> 
<label>Hårdvara</label>

<p>
     <label for="router">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="router" value="router" />
        <span>4G-Router med Data-SIM </span>
      </label>
</p>
</div>
```
Bur 4 of them